# How to connect to server with only username and public ssh key?

Tags: django, ssh, amazon-ec2, winscp

I want to use a batch file to connect to a amazon server by using the ssh private or public key.

I have tried

> open sftp://user:password@example.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
>
> psftp fred@server.example.com

in the script but I am not able to connect to the server. I am getting this error.

disconnected no supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey)

I am able to connect it from putty. I want a batch file to connect to the server and restart the django project in that.

If I am able to connect then I just need to go the path of my django project and run the command

> manage.py runserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -i PrivateKey.pem username@server.example.com
```